# "There's no line to end" with math equations

Tags: errors

I think the best way to describe what is going on is just show an example of where I am seeing these errors.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=4.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}



\pagestyle{fancyplain}

\begin{document}

\section{Some section title}
Text 

\subsection{Some subsection title}
Here is my paragraph about things, with a random inserted math thing $\frac{\pi}{3} \neq 1$.  Then I start a new math thing

\[3>1\]  % This is the line where I am getting an error

Here is more text.  No error.

\end{document} % oddly there is an error here to, same one.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code snippet a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). It runs fine with a minimal preamble on my system.

Comment: the best way is always to make a small document that shows the error. The error in the  title is given by mis-use of `\\ ` but there  is no `\\ ` in the fragment here.

Comment: There was not `\\\`  anywhere near the error I had.

Comment: Your MWE works without any error.

Comment: *If* the very example you are showing produces an error on your machine, then there is an issue with your LaTeX installation. So you may want to update it.

Comment: we can not debug this as the posted code shows no error. We can help you debug it  if you provide more information. Start by copying the file above to a new document and check you get the error, then delete every `\usepackage` that you can delete while still showing the problem (this greatly helps tracing the issue) then edit the question to show the new smaller tex file and also show the full log file with the error.